# Where I store the custom exceptions in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need to create a custom exception. But I dont have a clue where to store the file. In my opinion is app/Errors/NameException.php the right place. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a fine place to store your Exceptions. The final choice does not matter much as there is no convention set for this type of classes. The autoloader will find them anyway if you declare them correctly.

Comment: Okay thanks for the statement. Btw thumbs up for your keynode at #forumphp.