# Where I store the custom exceptions in cakephp 3.0.11?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to create a custom exception. But I don't know where to store the file and how I call the Custom Exception reference?

> This [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410054/where-i-store-the-custom-exceptions-in-cakephp-3) did not work, this folder structure does not exist in this version.

My current folder structure:

[image]

**Note:** CakePHP 3.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the accepted answer on the [question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410054/where-i-store-the-custom-exceptions-in-cakephp-3) you will see it doesn't matter where you place the exception as there is no Cake convention for where to put these. Using namespacing correctly the autoloader will find them.

Personally would put it somewhere like `src/Error/CustomException.php` (you can create the folder structure for yourself even if it doesn't exist), but at the end of the day it is up to you.